# Creating a typescript type for displaynames

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react component that receives the following props

```
type Props = {
    name: string;
    businessKey: string;
    isin: string;
    assetCurrency: string;
    assetType: string;
    assetSector: string;
    riskCurrency: string;
    domicile: string;
    industry: string;
    priceUnit: string;
}
```

I need to generate display values for each key so I create the helper type

```
type DisplayNames = {
  [k in keyof Props]:string
}
```

and create the display values

```
const displayNames : DisplayNames = {
  name: "Name",
  businessKey: "Business Key",
  isin: "Is In",
  assetCurrency: "Asset Currency",
  assetType: "Asset Type",
  assetSector: "Asset Sector",
  riskCurrency: "Risk Currency",
  domicile: "Domicile",
  industry: "Industry",
  priceUnit: "Price Unit"
}
```

Now, when looping over the props passed to the component I get the following error

```
Object.entries(props).map(e => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>{displayNames[e[0]]}</p> // ERROR Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'DisplayNames'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'DisplayNames'
      <p>e[1]</p>
    </>
  )
})
```

How can I solve this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your `DisplayNames` type is equivalent to `Props`; not sure why you defined it. Maybe `Props` has some non-`string` properties but `DisplayNames` is all `string`?

Comment: Functions like `Object.entries()` and `Object.keys()` return wider types than people like because it's possible for objects to have more properties than the TS compiler knows about.  You can work around it by using type assertions, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8x90w).  See the answers to the linked questions for more information.

Comment: Note `{[k in keyof Props]:string}` uses the unconventional type parameter name `k` instead of the more conventional name `K`.  It is a *type*, not a *key name*, so generally we use UpperPascalCase names to show it's a type and not a value (and single letters to show it's a type parameter and not a specific type)

Comment: @jcalz You're right. `DisplayNames` is actually redundant. Didn't even consider that.